# Redirection of IP to Minecraft server with PHP

Tags: php, redirect, dns, ip, minecraft

I have a local Minecraft Server set up. I decided to get myself my own domain, because ips arent really pretty. The problem is, that because the ip address of my router changes every night, I can't just do a A-record to my ip address. Instead I need a dynamic dns provider which allows me the use of my own domain. I could not seem to find one, so I coded it by myself with php (I have a free web server with a static ip address). Here's the code of the .php-file:

```
<?
    $usernameTest = $_GET["username"];
    $passTest = $_GET["pass"];
    $ipaddr = $_GET["ipaddr"];

    $username = "USERNAME";
    $pass = "*****";
    $port = ":25565";
    $serverIPtxt = "serverIP.txt";

    if(file_exists($serverIPtxt)) {
        if($usernameTest == $username) {
            if($passTest == $pass) {
                $a = fopen("$serverIPtxt", "w");
                fwrite($a, $ipaddr);
                fclose($a);
                echo $ipaddr;
            }
        } else {
            $a = fopen("$serverIPtxt", "r+");
            $dynIP = fread($a, filesize($serverIPtxt));
            fclose($a);

            $url="http://".$dynIP."".$port;
            header("Location: $url", true);
            die();
        }
    }
?>
```

My router is automaticly applying the correct ip address, so in theory I should be able to connect to the minecraft server with my new domain, but I cant. Instead Minecraft gives me this error:

```
[13:52:38] [Client thread/INFO]: Connecting to DOMAIN, 25565
[13:52:39] [Server Connector #5/ERROR]: Couldn't connect to server
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: DOMAIN/IPADDRESS:25565
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:716) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:208) ~[NioSocketChannel.class:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:287) ~[AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.class:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528) ~[NioEventLoop.class:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468) ~[NioEventLoop.class:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382) ~[NioEventLoop.class:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354) ~[NioEventLoop.class:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116) ~[SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.class:4.0.23.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
```

What am I doing wrong? Or does Minecraft just not support php redirects?

Comment: You want to use a dynamic ip updater client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minecraft does not use HTTP! It uses its own protocol based on TCP.

The best option, which I have used in the past, is to run a dynamic ip updater client.

1. Get yourself a [No-IP domain name](http://www.noip.com/) (e.g. `myname.ddns.net`)
2. Download the [dynamic updater client](http://www.noip.com/download) (available for Windows, Mac or Linux)
3. Set your custom domain name as a CNAME to point to `myname.ddns.net` (your NoIP domain name)
4. Give players your custom domain name (e.g. `myname.com`). This will refer the client to `myname.ddns.net` through the CNAME record which will in turn refer to your dynamic IP (e.g. `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`) as an A record.

After this you will be able to connect to your server with your custom domain and the dynamic updater will keep the dynamic IP up to date automatically.

Comment: I had this solution before, but I don't want anything like .ddns.net, but rather my own domain with .play at the beginning

Comment: @derkaländer Did you read step 3? The No-IP domain is not shown to your players - you can just give them the custom domain name.

Comment: Just wanted to tell you, that I found another solution. My router allows me to change its settings from all over the world with a special url. Because this url points to my ip I simply set my domain as a CNAME to that url. But your idea would work too, of course.